# $R$-module strcture on $M\oplus A$ so that it becomes a $R$-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, $A$ an associative $R$-algebra without identity and $M$ a $A$-bimodule.

I read I can endow $M\oplus A$ with a structure of $R$-algebra with the product $$(x, a)(y, b):=(x\cdot b+a\cdot y, ab).$$

My question is, what is the $R$-module structure on $M\oplus A$ for it to become an $R$-algebra with the above multiplication?

When $A$ has identity then every $A$-module is a $R$-module so $M\oplus A$ would have a ``natural'' module structure but in this case I don't know how to proceed.

Thanks.